# Android Allow Unchecking but Not Checking

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a Checkable ListView, I want to allow the user to check 15 items. Once they have checked 15 items I want to make it so they can no longer check any items but they can uncheck as they please.

Comment: I allow the user to check 15 items, when the user has 15 items checked I want them to no longer be able to check a box. I don't see why this is bad.

Comment: I have reworded the problem. I would post some code, but I'm not sure where to start. Can you even make it so a CheckBox can be unchecked but not checked?

Comment: You can probably use a counter as items are checked, and when your limit is reached start reversing the action when another one is checked (if it's checked, and you've reached the limit, set it to unchecked again). I've never tried this on Android, though, so I'm not sure how the code would look. (Better wording, BTW - removing my previous comments.)

Comment: I think a counter would be a great solution also for the counter you should set an onCheckedChangeListener and manage your counter from there, when your counter reach maximum you could set some recursive way to check if checkboxes are checked and disable al the ones that are not, also you should reduce your counter when check is removed